# Unable to connect to MySQL using Trilogy gem in Rails 7.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm not able to connect to mysql using trilogy gem in Rails 7.1.2.
I changed adapter: mysql2 to adapter: trilogy in database.yml

If I don't add any gems to Gemfile then ruby console says

```
Error loading the 'trilogy' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? trilogy is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

If I add gem 'trilogy' it says

```
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/trilogy_adapter.rb:61:in `rescue in new_client': No such file or directory - trilogy_connect - unable to connect to /tmp/mysql.sock (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/trilogy-2.6.0/lib/trilogy.rb:16:in `_initialize': No such file or directory - trilogy_connect - unable to connect to /tmp/mysql.sock (Trilogy::SyscallError::ENOENT)
```

So I'm not sure how this thing is supposed to work. If anybody tried to use it?

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: trilogy
  timeout: 5000
  username: user
  password: password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_db
```

UPDATE:

I was able to connect after adding host: 127.0.0.1 row

```
default: &default
  adapter: trilogy
  host: 127.0.0.1
  timeout: 5000
  username: user
  password: password
```

Comment: According to `activerecord-trilogy-adapter`: *"Rails v7.1+ includes Trilogy support by default making this gem unnecessary"* so you can drop that. Your second error just sounds like you config might be wrong. Can you post your database.yml?